# jQuery plugin for ajax select fill

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created my first jQuery plugin, so please try to understand :)

My plugin code looks like so:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.ajaxSelect = function(options) {
    var $this = this;
    //options
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    //disable select
    if ($.ui.selectmenu && settings.selectmenu && settings.disableOnLoad) {
        $this.selectmenu('disable');
    }
    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: settings.type,
        contentType: settings.contentType,
        url: settings.url,
        dataType: settings.dataType,
        data: settings.data
    }).done(function(data) {
        var n = data.d || data;
        var list = "";
        $.each(n, function(i) {
            list += '<option value=' + n[i].Id + '>' + n[i].Nazwa + '</option>';
        });
        $this.filter("select").each(function() {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append(list);
            if ($.ui.selectmenu && settings.selectmenu) {
                $this.selectmenu();
            }
        });
        settings.success.call(this);
    }).fail(function() {
        settings.error.call(this);
    });

    return this;
};

var defaults = {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: null,
    async: true,
    selectmenu: true,
    disableOnLoad: true,
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
};
})(jQuery);
```

Demo of usage is available at [http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/ncWEw/](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/ncWEw/12/)

What I was trying to accomplish:

- Select multiple elements at one time
- Filter only selects from selected items (in case selector would select other elemnts)
- Makes only ONE request to server
- First build option string and then append it instead of adding items in loop
- Specify 2 callbacks: one for error and second for success

I think that it would be better to use more of deferred objects, but I don't have idea how.
Any improvements and hints are welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your demo throws errors in console, something about `uniqueId` in ui.selectmenu.

Anyway:

1. You can expose `$.ajax` deferred so someone may use all features of `jQuery.Deferred` which is already there.
2. Call success callback with data as argument.

   ```
   settings.success.call(this, n);
   ```
3. If you do not want to do anything special in case of failure, and just want to provide `this` to error callback, you do not have to create closure there.

   ```
   .fail( settings.error );
   ```

   ..., unless you want to hide other rejection arguments.
4. Do not use `each` if `for` do the same (for performance reason):

   ```
   for( var index = 0; index < n.length; index ++){
     list += '<option value=' + n[index].Id + '>' + n[index].Nazwa + '</option>';
   }
   ```
5. Personally I don't like single char variable names, as they are really painful for future development

---

1. Instead of `$(this).empty();$(this).append(list);` you can simply use `$(this).html(list);`
2. You can expose jQuery.Deffered, for example as `this.promise = $.ajax(...`, example in here http://jsfiddle.net/dhRRN/5/
3. I would suggest also applying received options to ajax call, so your plugin's user could also alter request itself.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips :) I've updated my demo to remove all errors, and I changed `each` to `for`. Could You please show how should I change my code to use `Deferred`? I suppose I could add data to success callback, but in my case I wont need it later. Could You take a look at it again?

Comment: Regarding adding/hiding data for callback, I have added new #3.

@Misiu: I'm not exactly sure how are you going to use your plugin. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/dhRRN/) you have quick example how to expose `jQuery.Deferred` promise.

Comment: I'll be using this mostly in reports. For example I need to filter some data based on employees. I have 4 places to specify employee (employee that took order, one that collect all items in order, one that shipped etc) and the list I can choose is the same for every select. So my main idea was to fill multiple selects with same data that comes from ajax request and to do only one request for all selects. This is just a scratch rather than full working plugin, but I would like to create something usefull not only for me :)